# null exception with not null value

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

So I have this method here:

```
    public async Task<PixelData> GrabPixelData(string imageFileName)
    {
        if (!ImageDictionary.ContainsKey(imageFileName))
        {
            // doesn't exist yet, so load it
            PixelData pd = await LoadPic(imageFileName);
            ImageDictionary.Add(imageFileName, pd);
        }

        var test = ImageDictionary[imageFileName];

        return ImageDictionary[imageFileName];
    }
```

The debugger says "test" contains an object of type PixelData (with real, non-static values).

When it returns to the calling method, however, it says there is a null reference exception on that line:

```
    private async void LoadPic()
    {
        myObject.pixelData = await rootPage.GrabPixelData("obj1.png");
    }
```

MyObject is not null either (according to the debugger) ...

Is it that a Task gets returned?

EDIT:

ImageDictionary is Dictionary.

Comment: will you please give definition of your ImageDictionary

Comment: The snippet you have here doesn't compile, both because you can't await a void return, and because the LoadPic method you're calling doesn't accept any parameters, as well you're assigning that value to a `PixelData`. Do you have another overload of the LoadPic method you're not showing?

Comment: @Preston: Sorry for the confusion. I the loadPic() method that calls the GrabPixelData is in another class and doesn't take any parameters. I realize that's a little confusing. So far I've tried to navigate the async thing by adding methods, so there's a lot of repeat names :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `LoadPic` function to return `Task`:

```
private async Task LoadPic()
{
    myObject.pixelData = await rootPage.GrabPixelData("obj1.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `GrabPixelData` clearly returns a `Task<PixelData`> instance and not `PixelData`.
 So yes, your guess is correct, it is returning a `Task` instance.